# Display data from mysql database in listView using fragment

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to develop my first app, which contains a navigation drawer. I am currently trying to read data from a mysql database (running on xampp) and display it in a ListView. I've read many many tutorials, but since my .java class is extending Fragment (due to NavigationDrawer), I wasn't able to find a working solution. After many hours of reading and testing, I came up with the following (I know it's not the most noble way, but anyway...). Unfortunately, when trying in emulator, the app keeps stopping. In my opinion, there has to be a problem with the method getData().Anyone got an idea why? Thanks a lot for your help!
Cheers,
keja

```
public class newsFragment extends Fragment{

    View myView;
    ListView lv;
    String address = "http://127.0.0.1/android/words.php";
    InputStream is = null;
    String line = null;
    String result = null;
    String[] data;
    JSONObject jo = null;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_layout,container,false);

        lv = (ListView)myView.findViewById(R.id.lv);
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy((new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build()));

        getData();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        return myView;
    }

    private void getData(){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //READ IS CONTENT INTO A STRING
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line).append(" \n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //PARSE JSON DATA
        try{
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
            data = new String[ja.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){
                jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
                data[i]=jo.getString("name");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
    data = new String[ja.length()]; 
    for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){
        jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
        data[i]=jo.getString("name");
   }
    //here u pass data to arrayadapter and load to list view..

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! Your solution stops my app from crashing. Unfortunately, it still won't display the data in the listView :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution! The problem was the "server" address. The emulator does not seem to like "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", so I had to change it to my dynamic IP address. :-)